# Monitor Internet bandwidth

Tags: monitoring, bandwidth

We have an IPCop firewall/proxy installed in our network, and although I can use iftop to somewhat take a look at how the clients are using the Internet, is it possible to monitor it from outside the proxy with something like ntop?

Note that I'm not interested in LAN traffic, only traffic that goes to/from the Internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find something that wouldn't also mix LAN traffic, so I settled for [IPTraf](http://iptraf.seul.org/). I do have to use it from the firewall machine, but since it's a text program it's no big deal.

By using filters and named MACs, I can quickly take a look at Internet traffic.

I also found an interesting program called [EtherApe](http://etherape.sourceforge.net/). It graphs local network connections, [check it out](http://etherape.sourceforge.net/images/v0.9.3.png).

Another simple monitoring tool, [BandwidthD](http://bandwidthd.sourceforge.net/).

[Cacti](http://cacti.net/screenshots.php) looks interesting too, but too bloated for what I want.

Answer (score 5):

Have ntop kick out netflow data and you can get all sorts of fun reports.

http://www.ntop.org/netflow.html

http://www.networkuptime.com/tools/netflow/

Some people do just write their own flow parsers as well if you're into that sort of thing.

More information about netflow data:

http://www.manageengine.com/products/netflow/cisco-netflow.html
http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/HealthCheck/netflow_monitoring.htm

Comment: would any of this solution work in a sonicwall enviornment?

Comment: Which model sonicwall?

Comment: No NetFlow available :(

Answer (score 4):

We've used IPAudit http://ipaudit.sourceforge.net/.  It could give you pretty granular info about outgoing/incoming bandwidth.

Here are some screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Comment: That looks handy, but I couldn't get it to play with gnuplot from Ubuntu 8.10